# Updating windowStyle of WindowGroup in macOS SwiftUI-life cycle

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I want be able to update windowStyle of my App via ContentView, I tried 2 approach, but both failed! Looking to solve the issue with macOS SwiftUI-life cycle.

```
@main
struct macOSApp: App {

    @State private var windowToolbarStyle: Bool = false

    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(windowToolbarStyle: $windowToolbarStyle)
        }
        .windowStyle(windowToolbarStyle ? TitleBarWindowStyle() : HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())

    }
}
```

---

```
@main
struct macOSApp: App {

    @State private var windowToolbarStyle: Bool = false

    var body: some Scene {
        
        if windowToolbarStyle {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView(windowToolbarStyle: $windowToolbarStyle)
            }
        }
        else {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView(windowToolbarStyle: $windowToolbarStyle)
            }
            .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't say "it failed" without giving us any details of _why_ it failed. No error message? No exceptions? Nothing logged to syslog? Etc?

Comment: @Dai: I know that, but I do not think the issue can be solved via my approaches, that is why I did not include them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't currently possible using the SwiftUI app lifecycle. [`SceneBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenebuilder) doesn't implement `buildEither` or `buildIf` methods, which are required to support conditionals. Compare to [`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder#), which does implement them and supports conditionals.